# Implement a notification that is displayed regardless of where I am surfing

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I would like to implement a notification system is ReactJS/JS where the message is displayed at the bottom of the screen regardless if the page from which the notification is invoked is the active tab or not, minimized or not. Basically I have implemented a timer, and I would like to play the timer and go and work on something else on another browser tab until the timer clock is up. When the timer clock is up, I would like to receive a a message notification (not sound) to know that the timer clock is up to do what I am supposed to do next. Is this feasible?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's an easy way to do this across pages in the browser, but you can use the [notification API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/notification) to send a notification through the whole system which can then process the notification.

[Here](https://medium.com/javascript-dots/creating-browser-notification-in-javascript-79e91bfb76c8)'s a Medium article to get you started